# Area and region bounded by a curve

Tags: integration, area

Show that the region  bounded by the curve y=2x-x^2  and the line y=x
when rotated about the y-axis is  π/6 u^3.

I'm after some working to show this solution is true. I would like a step by step process.

Comment: I would like your context first. You haven't show much effort in your previous questions so please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I get confused with rotating the line about an axis as to whether it should be changed to opposite axis etc. a starting point at least would be appreciated.